# Amazon Neptune full text search query not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to implement a full-text search for Neptune DB using elasticsearch manually but getting this error :

```
{"requestId":"bcb16f6b-7e60-4e71-b0d8-a6a4a9b38b00","code":"MalformedQueryException","detailedMessage":"Failed to interpret Gremlin query: null"}
```

Here is my document:

```
{
    "entity_id": "f8b9726f-74f9-a0e0-5fbd-b609bbb14f89",
    "entity_type": [
        "suggestions"
    ],
    "document_type": "vertex",
    "predicates": {
        "title": {
            "value": "samsung mobile"
        }
    }
}
```

query:

```
g.withSideEffect('Neptune#fts.endpoint','elasticsearch cluster end point').withSideEffect('Neptune#fts.queryType', 'match').V().has('title','Neptune#fts samsung').local(values('title').fold()).limit(5).valueMap().toList()
```

it is giving error only if I am putting an existing word in search i.e Samsung but if I am searching for an unavailable word it worked fine not throwing any error.
Not sure what is wrong here, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: When you say manually, did you populate the ElasticSearch cluster yourself or let Neptune do it for you? Also in the query, did you specify the Neptune cluster or the ES cluster name on the `Neptune#fts.endpoint` side effect? It needs to be the ES endpoint.

Comment: Under this side effect in the query: withSideEffect('Neptune#fts.endpoint','nwptune end point') are you putting the Neptune endpoint or the endpoint of the Elasticserch cluster?  It should be the elastic search cluster

Comment: @KelvinLawrence, bechbd, Sorry for that it was elasticsearch endpoint actually. It is working fine, the problem was with ``` local(values('title').fold()) ```  I removed this and it is now working fine. Can anyone tell me what this local did actually?

Comment: I added an answer below and a reason why the query did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `local` step you showed will, for each 'title' property found, create a list with that property in it. Without the local step all values found would be wrapped into a single list if you just did `values('title').fold()` .

Note, however, and this is probably why your query was failing,  that you cannot add a `valueMap` step after that `local` step as you would be trying to apply `valueMap` not to vertices but to one or more lists of strings coming out of the `local` step.